# How to access methods in a parent class from the generic class?

Tags: c#, html-helper, fluent

Here is what I am trying to do.

To create a custom Html Helper with Fluent API, I have created this:

```
public interface IHelper:IHtmlString
{
    IHelper AddClass(string className);
    IHelper Attributes(object htmlAttributes);
}

public class Helper : IHelper
{
    private readonly Alert _parent;

    public Helper(Alert parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
    }

    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
        return ToString();
    }

    public IHelper AddClass(string className)
    {
        return _parent.AddClass(className);
    }

    public IHelper Attributes(object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return _parent.Attributes(htmlAttributes);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _parent.ToString();
    }
}
```

The `Alert` class:

```
public interface IAlert : IHelper
{
    IHelper HideCloseButton(bool hideCloseButton);
    IHelper Success();
    IHelper Warning();
}

public class Alert : IAlert
{
    private readonly string _text;
    private AlertStyle _style;
    private  bool _hideCloseButton;
    private ICollection<string> _cssClass;
    private  object _htmlAttributes;

    public Alert(string text, AlertStyle style, bool hideCloseButton = false, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        _text = text;
        _style = style;
        _hideCloseButton = hideCloseButton;
        _htmlAttributes = htmlAttributes;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "";
    }

    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
        return RenderAlert();
    }
    // private method RenderAlert() is omitted here.

    public IHelper AddClass(string className)
    {
        if (_cssClass == null) _cssClass = new List<string>();
        _cssClass.Add(className);
        return new Helper(this);
    }

    public IHelper Attributes(object htmlAttributes)
    {
        _htmlAttributes = htmlAttributes;
        return new Helper(this);
    }

    public IHelper HideCloseButton(bool hideCloseButton)
    {
        _hideCloseButton = hideCloseButton;
        return new Helper(this);
    }

    public IHelper Success()
    {
        _style = AlertStyle.Success;
        return new Helper(this);
    }

    public IHelper Warning()
    {
        _style = AlertStyle.Warning;
        return new Helper(this);
    }
}
```

The problem is the constructor of my `Helper` class directly access the `Alert`. Then it is difficult to change my `IHelper` and `Helper` into generic `IHelper<T>` and `Helper<T>` to use for my other custom helpers like `DropDownList` and `CheckBoxGroup`.

Since `AddClass` and `Attributes` methods should be available to all other Html helpers, I definitely don't want to have duplicate code. But what is the correct way to write this generic class?

Comment: can you trim this code down to just what is neded to understand the question?

Comment: Agree. Let me remove some code.

Comment: You should be able to put the methods you need into its own type/interface, and constraint your generic type to that new type

Comment: @Jason, I guess your advice is instead of using `Helper<T>` class, I should use different implementations like `AlertHelper: IHelper<Alert>` and `CheckBoxGroupHelper:IHelper<CheckBoxGroup>`. Isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, Jason. Yes you did say "constraint your generic". I just didn't realize what that is. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interface containing `AddClass` and `Attributes`, apply that to your `Alert` class and add it as a type constraint (`IHelper<T> where T : IYourInterface`).

Comment: sounds like a good direction. What is it called? Can I have a link to some documentation to use the `where T` clause or an example page?

Comment: [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).